# Getting tweets into JQuery list, having issues with refresh

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile, twitter

I'm having difficulty figuring how A) if this is the best way to parse a Twitter JSON response and put it into a jquery list. B) why the `<li>` items fall apart when I refresh the page.

Here is how I'm loading the tweets

```
var _url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline/tortugatruck.json?callback=?&include_rts=1&count=3';
$.getJSON(_url,function(data){
for(var i = 0; i< data.length; i++){
        var tweet = '<p>'+data[i].text;
        var created = parseDate(data[i].created_at);
        var createdDate = created.getDate()+'-'+(created.getMonth()+1)+'-'+created.getFullYear()+' at '+created.getHours()+':'+created.getMinutes();
        tweet = tweet.parseURL().parseUsername().parseHashtag();
        tweet += '<div><div><a href="https://twitter.com/#!/CypressNorth" target="_blank" class="black">@CypressNorth</a></div><div class="right"><a href="https://twitter.com/#!/CypressNorth/status/'+data[i].id_str+'">'+createdDate+'</a></div></div>'
        //$("#twitter-feed").append('<p>'+tweet+'<p>');
        $("#twitter-feed").append($("<li><a href='#'>"+tweet+"</a></li>"));
        //$('#twitter-feed').listview('refresh');
    }
});
```

Here is my markup

```
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="twitter-feed">
            <li><a href="#">Tweets on a page</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

The first time I navigate to the page it looks fine (no styles but you can see the individual list items).
[image: defined list items]

But if you refresh the page, I lose the list item styles and navigation ability.
[image: can't tell the tweets apart]

Comment: Do you use document ready inside your code?

Comment: also if it isn't a problem mail me your example and I will fix it.

Comment: I don't think so, I'm not sure what document ready is.